OpenAPI Generator application won't start fails on bean of type 'org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest' not found
I have the Maven OpenAPI generator building successfully. However, when I attempt to run the generated application it fails with the following Spring error:
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.clientapi.api.RmaCasesApiController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest' in your configuration.

Here's the build section of my pom.xml:
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.openapitools.OpenApiGeneratorApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.8.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api/client-case-api.yml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <library>spring-boot</library>
                            <configOptions>
                                <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
                            </configOptions>
                            <packageName>com.example.clientapi</packageName>
                            <apiPackage>com.example.clientapi.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.example.clientapi.model</modelPackage>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

The plugin appears to generate the necessary model and api, packages as well as the SpringBoot Application main class.
I've tried setting the mainClass property to the OpenAPI generated Spring Boot Application class (I had to set this property to get Maven to successfully complete an "install" build) but still get this error whether run from the command line or within the IDE.
I could not find any generated classes implementing the NativeWebRequest interface, so the runtime error made sense. Any help would be much appreciated.
Hoping someone else has seen this problem.

I resolved this issue by changing the Spring Boot "spring-boot-starter-webflux" to "spring-boot-starter-web" in the dependency management. I must have some inconsistencies in the generator's configuration and the project's dependency management.
